# literature review slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I wanna create a beamer slide which consists of my literature review items. but I cannot find a good and comprehensive table or tikz graph which is suitable for my purposes. can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you make a sketch of what the output should look like?

Comment: This is because citing in a slide is not a good practice. Nobody will go back and forth during your talk. If your slides will be read offline then still it causes disruption. Having a name and a year is sufficient. Then optionally you can have a bibliography at the end which beamer already supports.

Comment: absolutely correct, but I use an animated slide which lists the name of previous authors and says some highlighted features of their study. Do you know some well-animated graph in beamer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=blue!40!white,circle,text width=1cm,align=center] {first text};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=red!40!white,circle,text width=1cm,align=center] {first text};
        \end{tikzpicture}       
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=orange!40!white,circle,text width=1cm,align=center] {first text};
        \end{tikzpicture}       
    \end{column}
    \begin{onlyenv}<1>
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            text 1
        \end{column}    
    \end{onlyenv}
    \begin{onlyenv}<2>
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            text 2
        \end{column}    
    \end{onlyenv}   
    \begin{onlyenv}<3>
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            text 3
        \end{column}    
    \end{onlyenv}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Highlighting the current circle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.15\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[onslide=<1>{fill=blue!40},onslide=<2->{fill=blue!5},circle,text width=1cm,align=center] {first text};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[onslide=<2>{fill=red!40},onslide=<1>{fill=red!5},onslide=<3>{fill=red!5},circle,text width=1cm,align=center] {first text};
        \end{tikzpicture}       
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[onslide=<3>{fill=orange!40},onslide=<-2>{fill=orange!5},circle,text width=1cm,align=center] {first text};
        \end{tikzpicture}       
    \end{column}
    \begin{onlyenv}<1>
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            text 1
        \end{column}    
    \end{onlyenv}
    \begin{onlyenv}<2>
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            text 2
        \end{column}    
    \end{onlyenv}   
    \begin{onlyenv}<3>
        \begin{column}{.2\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
            text 3
        \end{column}    
    \end{onlyenv}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes Sam, but I wanna show the image and text for the first item, then hide it and show the text and image for the second item in the whole of the slide.

Comment: in addition, the left circles don't hide when the items passing.

Comment: @mohammadfazli please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. That is pretty cool. but only one problem, how the slide viewers can find that the "example-image-c" is related to circle with "orange!40!white" color. I mean if there was a guide flash that relates the circles to the boxes containing text and image, the viewers can relate the items to each other.

Comment: Dear Sam, no idea?

Comment: @mohammadfazli I added a method how to highlight the colour of the current circle.

Comment: @mohammadfazli Good to hear that the answer helped you. If you are satisfied with the solution, please consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows others that the question is solved and will remove it from the list of unanswered questions. As a bonus, this will not only give a reward to the answer, but you will get 2 reputation points, too.